# How to parse multidimensional json in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

How to parse this json in `flutter` by creating `model`

```
 {
 "Innerarray":[
    [{"abc":"A"}],
    [{"abc":"d", "hg":21}]
   ]
  }

Json['Innerarray'].map<List<dynamic>>((l)=>List<Mymodel>.from(l)).to list();
```

It's not working please help me to parse this `json`

Comment: do you have only `abc` and `hg` in map or have more item in them?

Comment: You can use one of these tools which will generate your models from json https://app.quicktype.io or https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

Comment: Ther is more items in array obj this is only sample

Answer (score 0):

```
class Autogenerated {
    List<List>? innerarray;

    Autogenerated({this.innerarray});

    Autogenerated.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        if (json['Innerarray'] != null) {
            innerarray = <List>[];
            json['Innerarray'].forEach((v) { innerarray!.add(new List.fromJson(v)); });
        }
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        if (this.innerarray != null) {
      data['Innerarray'] = this.innerarray!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
        return data;
    }
}

class Innerarray {


    Innerarray({});

    Innerarray.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: This model class not valid